# pandas total of the result of multiplying two values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I generated a DF that looks like this by merging a bunch of other DFs:

[image]

The price for NA always .015 and AS is always .0065. The same website can be in a multiple regions but I want to know the total pricing by region.

Goal is to end up with 2 dataframes one of them looks like this where price is in an additional column which is just Gb Used x Price Region:

DF1:

[image]

I think i can get the new colmun pretty easy by doing something like this:

```
df['Region Price Total] = df['Gb Used']*df['Price per Gb Per Region']
```

then merge it back in how do I do this across every row?

Then another dataframe which gives me the grand total of that by site by region
But how do I group by totals?

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste pics. Paste data a text in the question.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
>>> df
        website dept  Gb Used Price Region  Price per GB per Region
0  website1.com  AAA       10           NA                    0.015
1  website2.com  BBB       14           NA                    0.015
2  website3.com  CCC       20           NA                    0.015
3  website4.com  DDD       12           AS                    0.065
4  website1.com  AAA       10           AS                    0.065


>>> df1['Region Price Total'] = df1['Price per GB per Region'] * df1['Gb Used']
>>> df1
        website dept  Gb Used Price Region  Price per GB per Region  Region Price Total
0  website1.com  AAA       10           NA                    0.015                0.15
1  website2.com  BBB       14           NA                    0.015                0.21
2  website3.com  CCC       20           NA                    0.015                0.30
3  website4.com  DDD       12           AS                    0.065                0.78
4  website1.com  AAA       10           AS                    0.065                0.65


>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.groupby(['website', 'Price Region'])['Region Price Total'].sum()).reset_index(level=[0,1])
>>> df2
        website Price Region  Region Price Total
0  website1.com           AS                0.65
1  website1.com           NA                0.15
2  website2.com           NA                0.21
3  website3.com           NA                0.30
4  website4.com           AS                0.78
```

Comment: This is great, trying to understand df2. What does levels do and what if I wanted to add another column like dept to df2. When append it to group_by `pd.dataframe(df2.groupby['website','Price Region','dept']... it doesnt give me a unique url grouping.

Comment: without the `reset_index` part, it would be a `dataframe` with `multiindex`